# Text Input Effect Tied to <label>

Tags: material-design-lite

Why is the underline animation dependent on the `<label>` tag being present?  In other words, if you remove the `<label>` from the mdl-textfield the animation is removed also.

Anyone else notice this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of this CSS rule in [**Text field section**](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section):

```
.mdl-textfield__label::after {
    background-color: #3f51b5;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    left: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 10px;
}
```

If you check the above transition property, the animation is done when the input is focused:

```
.mdl-textfield.is-focused .mdl-textfield__label::after {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

***Note: If you need to remove the placeholder, Remove the text inside the label element, it will preserve the animation***

Comment: Thanks Manoj.  Should the effect be applied to the text field, regardless of the presence of a label markup?

Comment: Logically yes. But CSS rules as they have created is to separate the input from the border. It may go deep into UI considering their experience and knowledge ;)